# Developing Sharepoint 2010 List Extraction Off Site

Tags: import, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

```
        //Open SharePoint site
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(@"http://..."))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //Get handle for forms library
                SPList formsLib = web.Lists["FormsLib"];

                if (formsLib != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in formsLib.Items)
                    {
                        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

                        //Open XML file and load it into XML document
                        using (Stream s = item.File.OpenBinaryStream())
                        {
                            xml.Load(s);
                        }

                        //Do your stuff with xml here...}}}}
```

I tried adding both Sharepoint 2010 and 2013 SDK but still get no reference on the needed Assembly. What can you advise?

Olaf

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client this way:

```
string siteUrl = @"http://.../sites/.../";
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Title");
```

(here SP is a short alias for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client)

Then do a caml query via oList.GetItems().